# Fill Tuple item as a List inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a `Dictionary` in my code defined in a method as:

```
public Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<int>, int, int, int>> GetAuthorData(int startYear, int endYear)  
{  
   Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<int>>, int, int, int>> authorData;  

   foreach (var paper in Papers.Where(p => p.Year >= startYear && p.Year <= endYear))  
   {  
      authorData.Add(paper.PaperID,  
                     new Tuple<List<int>, int, int, int>(  
                     paper.CoAuthors, paper.PaperCategory, paper.VenueID, paper.Year)  
                    );  
   }  
   return authorData;  
}
```

The issue is while adding `paper.CoAuthors` as it is a `List<int>` so it'll not fill the list correctly being inside a tuple.

**UPDATE**

The list `Papers` is defined as:

```
public List<Paper> Papers { get; set; }
```

whereas the class `Paper.cs` is defined as:

```
public class Paper
{
   // Class constructor
   public Paper()
   { }

   public int PaperID { get; set; }
   public List<int> CoAuthors { get; set; }
   public int VenueID { get; set; }
   public int PaperCategory { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

**Using `GetAuthorData()` as:**

```
Dictionary<int, Author.AuthorData> tauthorData = eAuthor.GetAuthorData(year, year + 1);
foreach( var kvauthor in tauthorData)
{
   tw.WriteLine("PaperID: {0}, CoAuthors: {1}, PaperCategory: {2}, Venue: {3}, Year: {4}",  
   kvauthor.Key, kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors, kvauthor.Value.PaperCategory,  
   kvauthor.Value.VenueID, kvauthor.Value.Year);
}
```

**Required Output**

```
PaperID: 1, CoAuthorID: 23, PaperCategory: 6, VenueID: 3454, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 1, CoAuthorID: 24, PaperCategory: 6, VenueID: 3454, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 1, CoAuthorID: 25, PaperCategory: 6, VenueID: 3454, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 1, CoAuthorID: 26, PaperCategory: 6, VenueID: 3454, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 2, CoAuthorID: 27, PaperCategory: 7, VenueID: 3455, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 2, CoAuthorID: 28, PaperCategory: 7, VenueID: 3455, Year: 2016  
PaperID: 2, CoAuthorID: 29, PaperCategory: 7, VenueID: 3455, Year: 2016
```

How can we add to `CoAuthors` list correctly?

Comment: A dictionary of tuples of lists? I think you need to rethink your models here!

Comment: I've defined the structure of Dictionary as ID is int and value is a Tuple

Comment: @DavidG can you suggest where I'm wrong and how can it be normalized ?

Comment: I have to stack all these values inline, what other data structure can I use other than Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<int, AuthorData> GetAuthorData(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    var authorData = new Dictionary<int, AuthorData>();

    foreach (var paper in Papers.Where(p => p.Year >= startYear && p.Year <= endYear))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(paper.CoAuthors.Count.ToString());
        authorData.Add(paper.PaperID,
                        new AuthorData()
                        {
                            CoAuthors = paper.CoAuthors,
                            PaperCategory = paper.PaperCategory,
                            VenueID = paper.VenueID,
                            Year = paper.Year
                        });
        Console.WriteLine("After");
        Console.WriteLine(authorData.Last().Value.Count.ToString());
    }

    return authorData;
}

class AuthorData
{
       public List<int> CoAuthors { set; get; }
       public int PaperCategory { set; get; }
       public int VenueID { set; get; }
       public int Year { set; get; }
}
```

As for your printing code you need to do this:

```
Dictionary<int, Author.AuthorData> tauthorData = eAuthor.GetAuthorData(year, year + 1);
foreach (var kvauthor in tauthorData)
{
    foreach (var author in kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors)
    {
        tw.WriteLine("PaperID: {0}, CoAuthors: {1}, PaperCategory: {2}, Venue: {3}, Year: {4}",
        kvauthor.Key, author, kvauthor.Value.PaperCategory,
        kvauthor.Value.VenueID, kvauthor.Value.Year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would use LINQ syntax here all the way (`ToDictionary`)

Comment: And the issue is I've shown the way I'm using this method i.e. `GetAuthorData()` and not getting printing the values in `CoAuthors`

Comment: @Taufel please add a sample output to your question like this: `"PaperID: 100, CoAuthors: ???? , PaperCategory: 10, Venue: 5, Year: 2016"`

Comment: Yeah you yourself added example by commenting this whereas `????` will be the IDs for `CoAuthors` and if `PaperID = 100` have multiple `CoAuthors` in the list, so this `PaperID` and all the other items should get repeated as for as long we have elements in `CoAuthors` list

Comment: @Taufel then replace `kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors` with `String.Join(", ", kvauthor.Value.CoAuthors)`

Comment: @Taufel you want all the information repeated in each line for each CoAthor you want to print the `PaperID` again ?

Comment: I've shown the required output, I want as this because in your suggested format, its not distinguishable looks complex

Comment: Yeah, surely its all the same what required, one thing more if you don't mind, can we save all these data to Sql table in-spite of saving it in a text file?

Comment: @Taufel that would be another question. You need to mark this as answered and google how to save data to Sql table using c#.